# How to centre images with a gap imbetween

Tags: html, css

I am creating a website that has 3 images side by side with a bit of space in between.
I have made the images stay in the centre on my laptop but when I view it on another computer with a larger screen, the images move to the left rather than staying in the middle.
My code is as below

HTML:

```
<a href="MathsGamesYear1.html" id="rotator"><img alt=""     src="Image/Mathsgames.png" /> </a></a>

<a href="InformationBooklet1.html" id="rotator"><img alt="" src="Image/informationbooklet.png" /></a></a>

<a href="Year1QuizPage.html" id="rotator"><img alt="" src="Image/Quizzes.png" /></a></a>
```

CSS:

```
#rotator {
display: inline-block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
height: 200px;
padding: 85px;
text-align: center;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. If anybody knows any other way to centre 3 images together with a bit of padding in between that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the ID `#rotator` on all of the images. An ID can only be on the page once, so those should be classes instead. You're also closing the `<a>` tags twice, and no need for the trailing `/>` on `<img>` tags in html5.

To center them, since they are inline content, you apply `text-align: center;` to the parent. I don't see a parent in your code, so I added one called `.images`

To create space between the images, you can use left/right margin, which I've specified as `margin: 0 1em` where `1em` is the left/right margin, so there will be `2em` space between images. Adjust that as you see fit. You could also apply margin to just the center image with `.rotator:nth-child(2) { margin: 0 1em; }` or give the center image a class and use the class in the selector instead of `:nth-child(2)`

```css
.images {
  text-align: center;
}

.rotator {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 85px;
  margin: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
  <a href="MathsGamesYear1.html" class="rotator"><img alt="" src="Image/Mathsgames.png"></a>

  <a href="InformationBooklet1.html" class="rotator"><img alt="" src="Image/informationbooklet.png"></a>

  <a href="Year1QuizPage.html" class="rotator"><img alt="" src="Image/Quizzes.png"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It all works now apart from the images are close together and when i increase the padding it doesnt move the images apart.

Comment: @ilikecows adjust the margin instead.

Answer (score 0):

They are left aligned, your laptop screen is just too narrow to show it. Wrap them in a container with text-align:center:

```
.container{
   text-align:center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/58fwtu3c/